# How do I add an application that I created to one of my pages?

Tags: facebook

How do I add an application that I created to one of my pages?

Answer (score 0):

On your application info page, follow the 'View App Profile Page' on the left. On the Profile Page, follow the 'Add to My Page' link on the left.

Comment: I have the same question. But I can't find any link like "View App Profile Page." On the left of my app page (in the "app dashboard,") I see things like "Settings,", "App Details," "Localize," "Open Graph," "Roles," and "Insights." On the Page I created, there's nothing like that either. Trying to access the settings for the page doesn't give me the app control options I see when I'm running as myself.

Comment: This is an extremely outdated answer. I'm on a mobile device now but will update the answer tomorrow.